# Does the Axis matter for the consideration of "Sharing an alignment component"?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alignment

Specifically in regards to the *Insinuator* archetype for the *Antipaladin*, my question is really about their variant *Smite Impudence* feature.

It states:

> **Smite Impudence (Su):**
>
> Once per day, an insinuator can beseech the forces empowering him to punish their shared enemies. As a swift action, the insinuator chooses one target within sight to smite.
>
> *An insinuator cannot use smite against a target that shares an alignment with the outsider he has invoked for the day.*

And then goes on to describe functionality exactly as any other smite (+Cha to hit, +lvl to damage, etc.)

Essentially, at the start of each day, you pick an outsider that has an alignment within one step of yours, and then can *Smite* targets that have alignments that oppose it, ie LE can smite CG, CN, NG, and TN, but not LG, LN, LE, NE, or CE.

My question is, on the dual alignment axis of Good Vs Evil and Chaos Vs Law, how does Neutral apply? Specifically, does a LN creature have protection from an NE smite? They are both Neutral, but from a different Axis. **Does the Axis matter for the consideration of the alignment component, or is simply being Neutral on *either* axis enough to thwart the Smite?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, neutral on the Law–Chaos axis is not the same “component” as neutral on the Good–Evil axis. Alignment is treated as a grid; sharing a component means being in the same row and/or same column. NG and LN do not share anything.

Comment: I agree this is right but am left wondering if there is text confirming it in the system. I'll take a look if I have time.